# Harry Potter fanfiction where Harry is found guilty of the murder of Ginny Weasley and her lover

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

I read the story to while back, it was a Harry Potter/Draco Malfoy fan fiction. The story started with the death of Ginny Weasley and her lover (I believe it was a kind of brutal homicide). Harry found the corpses and the Ministry found him guilty. After that, Draco comes to help him run away and take him to a kind of secret place where he's hiding with his mom and little brother. I believe Harry was an Auror and a registered Animagus and had the shape of an eagle or maybe raven (it was a bird)? I do remember Draco rides a motorcycle, kind of like Sirius.

It does not have any stuff like Omegaverse or Mpreg, like the "unusual" stuff will be that is a M/M. I kind of believe I read it around 2009, more or less.

Comment: So not https://www.fanfiction.net/s/3381644/1/The-Things-We-Do-For-Freedom

Comment: Also probably not https://www.fanfiction.net/s/6516803/1/Guided-By-A-Star

Comment: Or https://www.fanfiction.net/s/6693854/1/Mistaken

Comment: I've been looking for the same fanfic.
Ginny was killed while being with her lover.
Does someone have the name?
I'm almost sure it was posted on fanfiction.net